# How to make custom Combo box control which have contain datagrid in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to make custom combo box which have contain datagrid and textbox too.
On clicks into combo box datagridview should be appear and selecting any row particular cell value of the datagridview added on the combo.
thanks in advance..

Comment: you want to implement this functionality in window form?using radcotnrols?

Answer (score 0):

As your question is written I have no idea how to answer it, I can't figure out how you could sensibly show a `DataGridView` inside a `ComboBox`. I'm writing this answer with the assumption that you mean that the form should have a `ComboBox` that are "linked" to a `DataGridView` rather than actually contain it.

If so, all you need to do is to add the `ComboBox` and `DataGridView` to the form, make the `DataGridView` invisible. Then you handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the `ComboBox`, in the handler, make the grid visibile, find the index of the row and column you want to show and write code like (code not tested so might not be correct):

```
grid.SelectedRows.Clear()
grid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex
grid.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex).Selected = True
grid.Show()
```